# Client side js files are not loading while using node.js with socketstream

Tags: node.js, socketstream

I'm using node.js with socketstream.Client side js files are not loading and also im getting ss is not defined error in client side while calling server method.

```
  This is my  app.js file

   var ss = require('socketstream'), 
  express = require('express');
  var app = express(); 
 // Code & Template Formatters 
 ss.client.formatters.add(require('ss-stylus')); 
 ss.client.templateEngine.use(require('ss-hogan')); 
   ss.client.define('main',
    { view: 'app.html', 
    css: ['libs/reset.css', 'app.styl'], 
   code: ['libs/jquery.min.js', 'app'], 
     tmpl: '*' }); 
 // Use Express to route requests 
  app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
  res.serveClient('main'); });
  server = app.listen(3000); 
  ss.start(server);
  // Append SocketStream middleware to the stack 
  app.stack = ss.http.middleware.stack.concat(app.stack);


   This is my server side method rpc method
     exports.actions = function(req, res, ss){

    return {

        saveUserInfo: function(name,pwd){
        console.log(name);
        console.log(pwd);
        res('name is '+name + '&'+'password is '+pwd);

      }

        }
       }
```

Comment: While using ss in client side to call the server side method im getting ss not defined error.ss.rpc('saveUserInfo',name,pwd,function(req,res){})

Answer (score 0):

The ss.rpc function takes the name of the rpc file, followed by the function name. So for example, if the file is called *server/rpc/authentication.js*, then you would call this from the client:

```
ss.rpc('authentication.saveUserInfo', name, pwd, function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Could you try moving these 2 lines:

    server = app.listen(3000); 
    ss.start(server);

To the bottom of your app.js file?

Comment: What versions of SocketStream & Express are you using?

Comment: express@3.0.5 and  socketstream@0.3.2

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and run that example you posted and see if I can figure out what's happening.

Comment: Can I check that your /client/views/app.html file includes a <socketstream/> tag in the <head> section?

Comment: :thanks.now only i added.now all files are loading but i'm getting can't find module entry.js error.

Comment: It looks like you're missing an entry.js file at /client/code/app/entry.js. If you add that, it should stop causing that error